# Почему нельзя использовать простой тест Стьюдента на средних, полученных по выборка-resample, чтобы найти доверительные интервалы для среднего?

Tags: статистика

У меня есть некоторые проблемы с пониманием того, почему я не могу просто использовать простой тест Стьюдента на средних, полученных по выборка-resample, чтобы найти доверительные интервалы для среднего.

Статистика выборки bootstrap может иметь распределение не очень близкое к нормальному (верно ли это и для оценки среднего значения?). Насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что новая выборка (средние по выборкам-resample) создается с некоторым шумом (из-за самого метода resample), который учитывается при построении доверительного интервала в bootstrap. Но не Student.

Comment: это явно не о том bootstrap-е, который описан в метке [tag:bootstrap]

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятен ход мысли, приведший к заключению, изложенному в вопросе.

Если ваше цель найти доверительный интервал для среднего, то классическая процедура говорит -  используем данные выборки, ПРИНИМАЕМ ДОПУЩЕНИЕ о нормальности выборки, строим доверительный инетрвал.

Процедура resample идет другом путем. Есть данные. Не делаем никаких предположений о их природе. Генерируем множество выборок из этих данных. Напрямую считаем диапазон (доверительный интервал) в который попадает заданный процент средних. Места тесту Стьюдента тут просто нет.

А как вы предполагаете применить тест Стьюдента полученных ресемплингом? И главное - для чего.